# How to use <router-link> in variable?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have an info box where I put informations about user registration status (for example that user with this email is registered). And I would like to add router links to this messages.

It's a HTML part of my template:

```
<div class="info" v-bind:class=infoClass v-html=info></div>
```

And a part of user registration method:

```
if (response.body === 'success') {
    this.infoClass = 'success'
    this.info = 'Success. You can <router-link to="/login">login now</router-link>.'
}
```

`<router-link>` doesn't work this way, so how can I put a link to my message?

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can use v-if if you want to show this in case of success:

```
<div class="info" v-bind:class=infoClass v-if="success">
    Success. You can <router-link to="/login">login now</router-link>
</div>
```

and in JS:

```
if (response.body === 'success') {
    this.infoClass = 'success'
    this.success = true // New data variable
}
```